# DDD, service and localization best practices?

Tags: design, domain-driven-design, localization

I'm building HTTP API with DDD principles. The end goal is that the server runs on some chosen language X but the clients can use what ever language the software supports. Service has state, but HTTP is stateless.

First without language:

```
storage = new MyStorage(params) // Can be anything from FS based to SQL, etc
service = new TODO(storage)
server = new build(service)
server.run()
```

`build` class is something like:

```
class build
  server: HTTPBase

  func build(service) 
    server.POST('/add', 
      func(req, resp)
        what = req.Get("param")
        res = service.DoSomething(what)
        if res == "Y"
          resp.Write("Everything went fine")
          return
        resp.Write("Oh noes!")
    )

    return server
```

Let's add a language (the wrong way with global state):

```
defaultLanguage = "eng"
storage = new MyStorage(defaultLanguage, params) 
service = new TODO(defaultLanguage, storage)
server = new build(service) // Oh noes!
server.run()

class build
  service
  server: HTTPBase

  func getLanguageFromURL(req, resp)
    self.service.SetLanguage(req.GetFromURL('$language'))

  func build(service)
    self.service = service // Oh noes!

    server.BaseRoute('/$language')
    server.Middleware(self.getLanguageFromURL)

    server.POST('/add', // This is now /$language/add
      func(req, resp)
        what = req.Get("param")
        // Because we're setting service's language in the middleware 
        // this becomes a mess because some other user using some other 
        // language might just done something and results to client then 
        // getting the result in wrong language.
        // (= This changes service's global state, and explodes)
        res = self.service.DoSomething(what)
        if res == "Y"
          resp.Write(translate("Everything went fine"))
          return
        resp.Write(translate("Oh noes!"))
    )

    return server
```

## So where to go?

### Always spawn new service in middleware?

```
defaultLanguage = "eng"
server = new build(defaultLanguage)
server.run()

class build
  service
  defaultLanguage
  server: HTTPBase

  func serviceMW(req, resp)
    storage = new MyStorage(self.defaultLanguage, params) 
    service = new TODO(self.defaultLanguage, storage)
    service.setLanguage(req.GetFromURL('$language'))
    req.Context['service'] = service


  func build(defaultLanguage)
    self.defaultLanguage = defaultLanguage
    server.BaseRoute('/$language')
    server.Middleware(serviceMW)

    server.POST('/add', // This is now /$language/add
      func(req, resp)
        // Now we have one time only service which is destroyed after request is complete
        service = req.Context.Get('service')
        what = req.Get("param")
        
        res = service.DoSomething(what)
        if res.X == "Y"
          resp.Write(translate("Everything went fine"))
          return
        resp.Write(translate("Oh noes!"))
    )

    return server
```

This is nicely isolated but starting the service might be really slow and eat lot of resources depending what it does.

### Clone/copy the service in middleware?

```
defaultLanguage = "eng"
storage = new MyStorage(defaultLanguage, params) 
service = new TODO(defaultLanguage, storage)
server = new build(service)
server.run()

class build
  service // main instance which gets cloned for each request
  server: HTTPBase

  func serviceMW(req, resp)
    // Create new instance
    service = self.service.clone() 
    service.setLanguage(req.GetFromURL('$language'))
    req.Context['service'] = service

  func build(service)
    // Create new instance
    self.service = service.clone()

    server.BaseRoute('/$language')
    server.Middleware(serviceMW)

    server.POST('/add', // This is now /$language/add
      func(req, resp)
        what = req.Get("param")

        // Cloned in middleware and destroyed after this request
        service = req.Context.Get('service')

        res = service.DoSomething(what)
        if res == "Y"
          resp.Write(translate("Everything went fine"))
          return
        resp.Write(translate("Oh noes!"))
    )

    return server
```

Adds isolation and removes possible startup slowdowns and resource hogs as they're done beforehand.

### Run a pool (array) of services for each language?

```
class build
  service[language] // service["eng"], service["fin"], ..
```

There's a lot of languages so it increases resource consumption. There could be also a mechanism that spawns service for a specific language when it's requested for the first time. Also service's that have been idle for N hours/minutes could be removed.

### Add language parameter to service's and repository's functions?

All `Service.DoSomething(param1)` becomes `Service.DoSomething(language, param1)`.

### Services/repositories never return only strings but some sort of translatable objects?

So you have something like:

```
result = service.DoSomething(param1)
actualResult = result.Translate(myChosenLanguage)
```

What is the DDD way of handling localization? Am I missing any options?

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time understanding most of your question so I’ll focus on the last two sentences: ‘*What is the DDD way of handling localization? Am I missing any options?*’

The goal of DDD is to tackle complex business logic. This is best done when the user issues commands. For example:

- a user enters some data in a form and presses a button
- the system loads the correct aggregate from persistence
- the system invokes the method on the aggregate with the data from the user
- the aggregate and it’s internals perform validation and change state
- the system persists the new state of the aggregate

If the validation fails, the method on the aggregate root can return a Result object, with a bool success, a string for the English error message (for convenience) and an enum for the error code. In the presentation layer, the enum can be mapped to a localized message. I would not put the localization in the domain layer; that creates unnecessary complexity and it really is a presentation concern.

Comment: But the service can be also presented to the user as a localized CLI application. You need to say things like "Enter your first name:", "X succeeded", etc. User won't understand something like [[<obj ref 0xc0ffee>]]. Thus language and in this case localization for multiple languages is needed. So how it is done in DDD?

Comment: Those are concerns of the presentation layer, not the business logic layer.

Comment: For example "a user enters some data in a form and presses a button" and it has errors such as something was in invalid format. These rules are in the business logic layer and forwards them for presentation. So does it forward object with wrapped objects like `FooFormError([InvalidFieldName([InvalidName])])` which then view parses into for example "FooForm: Name field: invalid name"? or does it directly just forward string "FooForm: Name field: invalid name"?

Comment: In that case I would have the method on the aggregate return a Result object, with a bool success, a string for the English error message (for convenience) and an enum for the error code. In your presentation layer, map the enum to the localized message.

Answer (score 0):

DDD is about how you model the domain knowledge. DDD could care if a user speaks some language but hasn't anything to do with the way the message is represented. This is an application concern, so it is definetly an application logic resposibility, thus only controllers/middlewares could know about the need to translate. Domain classes could store and retrieve text information in form of enums string label (eg. "messages.everything_fine" or "errors.oh_no")* and middlewares take care of the rest. How to handle translation to obtain efficiency? good question, but it's another question

*both options are valid...of course enums are less extensible but also more safe